# Python 3.4 invalid syntax in setup.py on ubuntu 14.04, why?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04, setuptools

I have a bug ([ussue #14 on github](https://github.com/gamenet/redis-memory-analyzer/issues/16)) in my python project rma. Installing it trow pip 1.5.4 with python 3.4 some got error like this:

```
Downloading/unpacking rma
Downloading rma-0.1.5.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/rma/setup.py) egg_info for package rma
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/rma/setup.py", line 47
    setup(**sdict, install_requires=['redis', 'tabulate', 'tqdm', 'msgpack-python'])
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip_build_root/rma/setup.py", line 47

setup(**sdict, install_requires=['redis', 'tabulate', 'tqdm', 'msgpack-python'])

             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
```

My own pip version 8.0.2 (python is 3.5).

I newby in python, sorry if this well known issue. I want to know - should i found way to fix it (if this is my issue) or just recommend to update pip to my user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package won't install on any Python version < 3.5, because the syntax is indeed invalid on anything but Python 3.5 and newer.

You can't put the `**kwargs` syntax in front of other keyword arguments. The two should be swapped:

```
setup(install_requires=['redis', 'tabulate', 'tqdm', 'msgpack-python'], **sdict)
```

Reporting this as a bug was the correct thing to do; the package states it supports Python 3.4 and up.

Python 3.5 added support for an arbitrary number of `*args` and `**kwargs` expansions through [PEP 448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations), opening the door for the above to work too.